# Circuit analysis with known current

Tags: circuit-analysis

For the circuit shown below:

[image]

It's obvious that $$\mathbf{i_1= 4 A}$$
So, is it acceptable to apply KVL to the left loop as follows:
$$\mathbf{3i_1+5i_1-3i_2-5i_3= 0}$$
$$ \mathbf{8i_1-3i_2-5i_3= 0}$$
substituting for $$\mathbf{i_1= 4 A}$$
$$ \mathbf{8*(4)-3i_2-5i_3= 0}$$

### $$ \mathbf{3i_2+5i_3= 32\qquad\qquad \fbox1}$$

### **Is equation 1 above accurate or not?**

Source:
FUNDAMENTALS OF ELECTRIC CIRCUITS, SIXTH EDITION By Charles K. Alexander, ISBN 978-0-07-802822-9

Comment: i1 isn't 4 amps; no, it's neither obvious nor true. Most of the 4 amps will flow through the 2 ohm resistor as a quick-look estimate.

Comment: What current does this notation denote?

Comment: The total current at any node =0. Change your assumptions.

Comment: What current are you trying to find, Io?

Comment: @Andy aka Why not? by looking at the leftmost leg I1 = 4 A

Comment: Nothing is obvious for an answer, except sum I=0 in a node (KCL) and sum V in a loop=0 (KVL) and \$5*i_o = v = i_o * 5 Ohm\$  and 4A = i1+i2

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 OK, if I want to take KVL at loop 1 what will it be?

Comment: See my answer for the number of total equations needed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this circuti with CCVS
[image]

We see three mesh currents marked \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$

Since fist mesh, current contains a current source we know that:

\$I_1 = 4A\$

Thus, we need to write two mesh loop equations.

For \$I_2\$ mesh:

$$-5I_O + (I_2 - I_3)1 + (I_2 - I_1)3 + 2I_2=0$$

and for \$I_3\$

$$-20 + (I_3 - I_1)5 + (I_3 - I_2)1 + 5I_O + 4I_3 = 0$$

And one additional the \$I_O\$ current is equal to:

\$I_O = (I_1 - I_3) = (4 - I_3)\$

And the solution is

$$I_1 = 4A$$
$$I_2 = 2.35294A$$
$$I_3 = 4.47059A$$

And for example

\$I_O = 4A - 4.47059A = -0.47059A\$

and \$3\Omega\$ reistor cutrrent is \$I1 - I_2 = 4A - 2.35294A = 1.64706A\$

The current in the 1-ohm resistor is equal to:

\$I_3 - I_2 =  4.47059A - 2.35294A = 2.11765A\$ So, the current entering the positive terminal of a dependent voltage source.

Answer (score 2):

What a lot of people struggle with when it comes to systems of equations is recognizing the easiest equations to make. It is pretty easy to go and make a problem like this overly difficult. It is also easy to start assuming things that are wrong, like you did, and make a mistake.

EDIT: To clarify the mistake you made was not including the voltage of the current source in your KVL equation.

Just to restate the obvious, this problem can be done with 3 equations because you only have 3 unknowns.

Now it comes to deciding which 3 equations to make. Using KVL on the left loop is difficult because there is a current source with no resistor. This means we don't know the voltage there (source transformation) . The right two loops make easy KVL equations because they have no unknown voltages. So how do we make that third equation? Think about KCL for that one.

The only way to get good at these is with practice unfortunately. But what you can do is look for the easiest questions first.

Comment: Oh OK. I0+I3 = 4. This is the third equation. Right?

Comment: There are several equations that will work. I believe that is one of them

Answer (score 0):

Q: How many equations do you need to solve a network with N Nodes, L mesh loops and Q components?

A: At least 1 per part plus Ohm's Law for each.

1. Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) has N−1 independent equations, where Sum of current going IN = Sum going Out
2. Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL) has Q−(N−1)independent equations (mesh loops), for Q quantity of parts and N nodes.

How many nodes?  6
Quantity of parts?  8
KCL equations?   5
KVL equations?  3

Mesh Loops are independent that usually do not contain other loops.

KVL (i1) is OK but where is KVL for i2, i3?

These currents are independent loops where you apply superposition to generate the resulting current in each part.

- using KCL 4A in =  i1+i2 OUT  on top and
  4A out = i1+i3 IN  on the bottom of the current source.

Can you create all the KCL and KVL equations now?